# Array of objects with conditonal

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, if-statement

So I am trying to return the price for the item that is looked up in this function:

What if the item isn't in the list??
And if it isn't I need to return

"No item found with that name"

How would I go about doing that?

```js
let items = [{
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

function priceLookup(array, item) {
  let results = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].itemName === item) {
      results = array[i].price
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: if item is not in the list then you won't get anything you'd get 0. Also I recommend you look at [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

Comment: or look at `Array.filter`.

Comment: init the `results` as `null`, because 0 is hipothetically a valid price value. Then just check if results is null - nothing found

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a different logic here like this:

- Instead of returning the `price` with default value 0, set it to `null`.
- **Case #1:** Item is found, then it returns actually price from the array.
- **Case #2:** Item is not found, then it returns price as null and then you can simply check for that and set the default value like:

  ```
  priceLookup(items, "abc") || "No item found with that name"
  ```

```js
let items = [{itemName:"Effective Programming Habits",type:"book",price:13.99},{itemName:"Creation 3005",type:"computer",price:299.99},{itemName:"Finding Your Center",type:"book",price:15}];

function priceLookup(array, item) {
  let results = null;
  var foundItem = array.find(a => a.itemName === item);
  if (foundItem)
    results = foundItem.price;
  return results;
}

console.log( priceLookup(items, "Creation 3005") )
console.log( priceLookup(items, "abc") || "No item found with that name" )
```

---

Or, you can simply do this also with less code:

```js
let items = [{itemName:"Effective Programming Habits",type:"book",price:13.99},{itemName:"Creation 3005",type:"computer",price:299.99},{itemName:"Finding Your Center",type:"book",price:15}];

function priceLookup(array, item) {
  return (array.find(a => a.itemName === item) || {}).price;
}

console.log( priceLookup(items, "Creation 3005") )
console.log( priceLookup(items, "abc") || "No item found with that name" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply rewrite your lookup function as follows:

```
function priceLookup(array, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].itemName === item) {
      return array[i].price
    }
  }
  return "No item found with that name";
}
```